# How to control appearance of EditText box?

Tags: java, android, timer, android-edittext

I intend to have an EditText box where a user can input data appear after a timer ends. To do this, I placed in in the onFinish section of my timer. This didn't work, because as soon as I access the screenview, the EditText box appears before the timer even starts (timer starts when a button is pressed). The box does go away when a user inputs their data and presses enter, as expected, but it appears before the timer even starts, which I do not want.

```
new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
                    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                    input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            switch (keyCode){
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                    Editable answer = input.getText();
                                    input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    if (answer.equals(loadG1)){
                                        score[0]=+1;
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();
```

This is the only part of my program where the EditText box appears, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Post the XML for the edittext

Comment: Whether you try to access the EditText inside code using findViewById or not, the EditText will be displayed in the containing activity. What you should do is, put `final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);` before the CountDownTimer and then use `input.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` to hide it. Inside onFinish() make the EditText visible to user using `input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

Comment: @MichaelStoddart I referred to my XML, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Birraa Alternative solution used, see comment on Justin's post. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `EditText` (`R.id.enterAnswer`) is being defined on an XML layout. So, you will need to set the default visibility to `android:visibility="gone"` in the XML file. Then, set `input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in your Java code when the timer is finished.

Comment: Thanks, I changed visibility to invisible in the XML file and then made is visible until enter is pressed in the Java file. No use of true or false though, are they actual Java commands or just general expressions?

Comment: Sorry - was using generalized expressions. I'll update answer with proper code as given by @CardDeath

Answer (score 2):

As Justin said, you need to set the visibility of your EditText to    android:visibility="gone"
in XML. You could get the reference of your EditText before the counter function and set input.setVisbility(View.GONE);

Just make sure this is done before the timer counts down to 0

Comment: Sorry only just saw birraas comment. :)